# porting vb6 app to VS2008 vb.net - make compiler flag unitialized form's private variable as error

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction

I can make the compiler give me an error (Use of variable prior to assignment) with:

```
private sub Test()
   Dim ord As Order
   Dim ord2 As Order
   ord2 = ord
end sub
```

but not with:

```
Friend Class frmReceiving
...

Private mobjOrder As Order 

...

private sub Testing()
   Dim ord2 As Order
   ord2 = mobjOrder 
end sub
```

How can I make it flag as error?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is not an error. `mobjOrder` will be initialized to `Nothing`. You then assign `Nothing` to `ord2`. That's a perfectly legitimate thing to do.

Comment: what's the diff between the 2 examples. why does mobjOrder get intialized to Nothing, but not ord in the first example?

Comment: In the first example, it's a local variable. In the second example, it's an instance variable.

Comment: ok, I see now after thinking about it. There IS no difference in the 2 assignments, the 2 objects are "Nothing", it just must be the compiler has no way of knowing if the private class member object has been intialized elsewhere prior to the assignment statement (though I would wish it could analyze all the places where it is used and determine if it is), whereas in the method it knows the local variable is unitialized.

Comment: @John. Surely the same argument applies to the first example. `ord` will be initialized to `Nothing` & assigning `Nothing` to `ord2` is legitimate. It's just that the compiler detects it and warns you because it's likely to be a mistake. As bmutch says the difference is that it's much harder to create a static analyser to help you with the second case.

Comment: @MarkJ: I don't know VB to that level of detail, but in C#, `ord` would _not_ be initialized to `null`. It would simply be a compiler error.

Comment: @John I hadn't realised that C# requires that all local variables must be initialised in a way that the compiler can detect through static analysis (just found the rules in the language spec). I'm not sure whether VB requires that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use the /warnaserror compiler option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xz9dxe5.aspx